# Scale hardcoded SVG image based on div size upon page load

Tags: html, css, svg, scale, viewbox

I have a `div` element which contains a `svg` graph (bunch of circles and edges), and I also set `viewBox` attribute on the `svg` element. The coordinates of the nodes and edges in the graph are hardcoded for a specified screen size (hence for a specified `div` size too) in `px`. With the desired `div` size, the graph loads nicely, and also scales up and down while the browser window is being resized.

However, my problem arises whenever the page is loaded under a different screen/`div` size, as the `svg` image remains the same for the specified `div` size before. This creates an image that is too large for smaller browser/screen sizes.

I set the following for the `svg` element:

```
<svg id="mygraph" preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMid meet">
```

and set its `viewBox` attribute using Javascript, immediately after the `div` element:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    document.getElementById("mygraph").setAttribute("viewBox", "0 0 " + $("#graphdiv").width() + " " + $("#graphdiv").height());
</script>
```

This does not resolve the problem. So what else can I try?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The viewBox defines the coordinate system used inside the svg, it doesn't change the size of the svg. If you have a viewBox you only need to set the width and height of the svg (using CSS for example) and it will render to that size.

Comment: True, I can change the width and height of the `svg` via Javascript. Or, I can just leave it the `viewBox` attribute fixed for the desired size, and that should take care of different screen/window sizes, as I've realized. Thanks!